# creating a time-shifted copy of a Pandas dataframe with a datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I wanted to do a time-series correlation of two dataframe; raw and old.  I have created a time-shifted copy of my first dataframe, called shifted_raw to compare with the old version.

I used

```
shifted_index=vraw_os_flight_data_df.index+timedelta(seconds=timeshift)
shifted_vraw_os_flight_data_df=vraw_os_flight_data_df.copy()
shifted_vraw_os_flight_data_df.index=shifted_index
shifted_vraw_os_flight_data_df.columns=['shifted_raw_altitude','shifted_raw_lat','shifted_raw_lon']
```

to create a copy of the raw dataframe with a shifted time index

This is the output of the two dataframes

```
2018-04-05 18:45:00    368.71
2018-04-05 18:45:01    368.76

2018-04-05 21:13:59    371.35
2018-04-05 21:14:00    371.40
Freq: S, Name: old_altitude, Length: 8941, dtype: float64

2018-04-05 18:44:50    368.71
2018-04-05 18:44:51    368.76

2018-04-05 21:13:49    371.35
2018-04-05 21:13:50    371.40
Freq: S, Name: shifted_raw_altitude, Length: 8941, dtype: float64
```

Note how the time in one is shifted by 10sec.  So the shift worked and both indices are datetime objects:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-05 18:45:00', '2018-04-05 18:45:01',
               '2018-04-05 18:45:02', '2018-04-05 18:45:03',
               ...
               '2018-04-05 21:13:57', '2018-04-05 21:13:58',
               '2018-04-05 21:13:59', '2018-04-05 21:14:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=0, length=8941, freq='S')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-05 18:44:50', '2018-04-05 18:44:51',
               '2018-04-05 18:44:52', '2018-04-05 18:44:53',
               ...
               '2018-04-05 21:13:47', '2018-04-05 21:13:48',
               '2018-04-05 21:13:49', '2018-04-05 21:13:50'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=0, length=8941, freq='S')
```

Yet when I try to merge the two dataframes by doing:

```
merged_dataframe=shifted_vraw_os_flight_data_df.merge(vold_os_flight_data_df, left_on=['shifted_raw_altitude'], right_on=['old_altitude'],how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

I get this error:

ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

The indices match type, and the columns match type.

So here is my noob question: what in the name of Mike am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can get by if I don't specify the columns to merge on.  But for future, I'd like to know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You specified `left_on` ,`left_index`, `right_on`, and `right_index`. Pandas by default, compares first `left_on` to `right_index` which is `shifted_raw_altitude` (`float64`) to the right_index (`datetime64[ns]`)

If you need to merge on multiple columns, including the index:

```
merged_dataframe = shifted_vraw_os_flight_data_df.reset_index().merge(
        vold_os_flight_data_df.reset_index(),
        left_on=['index', 'shifted_raw_altitude'],
        right_on=['index', 'old_altitude'],how='outer'
)
```